# Change paginator url in cakephp

Tags: url, cakephp, routes, paginator

I've see some cases of this problem, however, I haven't found my particular case.

I want to change this

```
http://localhost/dreyfus/trunk/home/birth/index/page:2
```

to this

```
http://localhost/dreyfus/trunk/home/cumple/index/page:2
```

I already changed on routes.php:

```
Router::connect('/cumple', array('controller' => 'birth', 'action' => 'index'));
```

but is not enough.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Router::connect('/cumple/*', array('controller' => 'birth', 'action' => 'index'));
```